# How to find in an ansible (yaml) dictionary a key from his value?

Tags: dictionary, filter, ansible, jinja2

I have this dictionary:

```
MyClouds:
  Devwatt:
    ExternalNetwork: PublicRSC
    Flavors:
      - Flavor_1cpu_1gb: Devwatt_1cpu_1gb
      - Flavor_1cpu_2gb: Devwatt_1cpu_2gb
      - Flavor_1cpu_4gb: Devwatt_1cpu_4gb
  Fuga:
    ExternalNetwork: Internet
    Flavors:
      - Flavor_1cpu_1gb: Fuga_1cpu_1gb
      - Flavor_1cpu_2gb: Fuga_1cpu_2gb
      - Flavor_1cpu_4gb: Fuga_1cpu_4gb
      - Flavor_1cpu_8gb: Fuga_1cpu_8gb
```

I have to migrate from one Openstack cloud to another, and one of my problem is to find correspondances between flavors.

I want to find which flavor (key) has the value "Devwatt_1cpu_2gb" in "Devwatt", and after get the value of the same key in "Fuga"

I tried a lot of solution (with-dict, when, jija filters, json_query) but I can't find a way to do that.

Please, may you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by Eric's answer and this [usefull resource](http://www.oznetnerd.com/jinja2-selectattr-filter/), I, finally, used this solution:

I changed a little bit my data structure and put it in a file matrice.yml:

```
MyClouds:
  Devwatt:
    ExternalNetwork: PublicRSC
    Flavors:
      - name: Flavor_1cpu_1gb
        FlavorName: Devwatt_1cpu_1gb
      - name: Flavor_2cpu_1gb
        FlavorName: Devwatt_2cpu_1gb
      - name: Flavor_1cpu_2gb
        FlavorName: Devwatt_1cpu_2gb   

  Fuga:
    ExternalNetwork: Internet
    Flavors:
      - name: Flavor_1cpu_1gb
        FlavorName: Fuga_1cpu_1gb
      - name: Flavor_2cpu_1gb
        FlavorName: Fuga_2cpu_1gb
      - name: Flavor_1cpu_2gb
        FlavorName: Fuga_1cpu_2gb
```

then I used these filters in my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    SourceFlavorName: "Devwatt_2cpu_1gb"

  tasks:
  - name: get flavors matrice
    include_vars:
      file: matrice.yml

  - name: Get generic name from flavor name of source cloud
    debug:
      msg: "{{ MyClouds.Devwatt.Flavors | selectattr('FlavorName','search','^'+ SourceFlavorName +'$') |map (attribute='name') | list }}"
    register: result

  - name: Get flavor name for target cloud from generic name
    debug:
      msg: "{{ MyClouds.Fuga.Flavors | selectattr('name','search','^'+ result.msg[0] +'$') |map (attribute='FlavorName') | list }}"
```

With this solution I can have any number of clouds and find easily correspondances between flavor from one source cloud to target cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a simple mapping using a dict where keys are "Devwatt" flavors and values are "Fuga" flavors, like this :

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    FlavorsMapping:
      Devwatt_1cpu_1gb: Fuga_1cpu_1gb
      Devwatt_1cpu_2gb: Fuga_1cpu_2gb
      Devwatt_1cpu_4gb: Fuga_1cpu_4gb
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: FlavorsMapping['Devwatt_1cpu_2gb']
```

Comment: Good idea ! It could be possible to use that for a relation with only two clouds. But actually it's more complicated. I have to describe a relation between one cloud (the source) and multiple target clouds. That's why I chose to have the same key (ex: Flavor_1cpu_1gb) and multiple values, one for each target clouds.

Comment: Then you could have one mapping dict for each target cloud.